# How to verify the Objects in SQL Server Database and TFS are in sync?

Tags: tfs

I am using SQL Server as a database and TFS 2008 as Source and Version Control. When I create a object in database respectively I will create the object in TFS as a sql file.

I am facing problem like some developers creating object in Database but they are not updating the TFS with the same.

How do I maintain the TFS and Database in sync and if any differences are there, how can I find easily  ?

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to only allow developers to add and modify SQL scripts in your TFS system. Then use build automation to execute those scripts against a clean database. That way, you are always 100% sure you can reproduce your database model and content from the items you have stored in TFS.